# R: add an element into a list

Tags: r

I would like to ask if it is possible to add an element into a list.
For example the list

```
L <- vector("list", 2)
L[[1]] <- vector("list", 2)
```

I want to become

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
NULL

[[1]]            # add an element and it becomes [[1]]
[[1]][[2]]                                       [[1]][[2]][[3]]
NULL                                             NULL  

[[2]]
NULL
```

Thank you all, in advance

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding what you want to do, but I don't think it will become `[[1]][[2]][[3]]` but it will be `[[1]][[3]]` (in other words, the third element in list `[[1]]`.

Comment: Are you just trying to insert a third item into list `[[1]]`? If so, `L[[1]][[3]] <- vector()` should work for you.

Comment: @mrdwab: You are right. Sorry, I was confused a little bit. Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code for list "L",

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
```

represents the first item in list `[[1]]` and can be referenced by `L[[1]][[1]]`.

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[2]]
```

represents the second item in `[[1]]` and can be referenced by `L[[1]][[2]]`. So, to add a new element into the list, you can just use:

```
L[[1]][[3]] <- vector()
```

Personally, I find it much easier to work with named elements though, since keeping track of those brackets can be somewhat tedious.